# How to position center horizontal 2 elements in a row in Relative layout

Tags: android, xml

I'm studying XML right now and I need a little help

What I need to do is to put a TextView followed by an ImageView in the Center Horizontal.

Here's the code:

```
 <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/party_p"

        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/TextView_congrats"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView_congrats"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Congrats Laura!"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"

        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"/>
```

I'm using Relative Layout for this project and I need to know how to put those elements in the Horizontal center.

Comment: You could wrap them both in a LinearLayout and give a `centerHorizontal="true"` value, or just add this `centerHorizontal="true"` to both of them, they'll center horizontally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this attribute in both views :

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```